# convert to Yii query builder

Tags: php, mysql, yii

i want to convert this to query builder expression.
i try a lot but i couldn't do it. please help me if you can

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("not connecting");
    mysql_select_db("skykeey",$connect) or die("no db :'(");

    $find1 =mysql_query("SELECT Count(*) FROM `mosqueculturalliablee` WHERE `email` ='$this->username'",$connect);
    $count1=mysql_fetch_row($find1);
```

i convert it myself to :

```
$find1 =Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select ('count(*) as num')
    ->from('mosqueculturalliablee')
    ->where('email=' . $this->username)
    ->queryScalar();
```

but it doesn't work and i get mysql syntax error

what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't included the quotes for `$this->username` in the query.

```
 ->where("email='" . $this->username."'") //outputs where email='username'
```

As an improvement you should use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) instead.

```
->where("email=:email")
->queryScalar(array(':email'=>$this->username));
```

Comment: another question, if i want to count the number of rows that selected in this query,what should i do? i want to save this value in a variable like $numrows

Comment: This should be asked as a separate question.